# google analytics setup, not tracking

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to implement google analytics on a page but it refuses to track anything.

the public domain is on **www.publicdomain.com**, when entering the page its redirected to: **www.publicdomain.com/sub1/sub2/index.php**

this website is hosted on another domain:

**www.privatedomain.com/publicdomain/sub1/sub2/index.php**

This is the GA code I'm using inside the body tag of the **index.php** file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-9999999-9']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'publicdomain.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

Any ideas of what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some things to check:

Are you using the correct UA number? (i.e. not 999999-99)

Are the GA cookies being created? (__utm[abcz])

Is the __utm.gif request being sent back to Google?  If not, is your browser blocking it? (i.e. is Do Not Track enabled?)